# Using Machine Learning to Identify Optimal Weightings

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, artificial-intelligence

I want to compare different documents based on similarity of words and conclude on their chances of being related. to estimate whether two documents are related, I am looking at the words that are included in both documents. I have harvested a lot of data, and for the 500 most used words in all documents (other than obvious filler words like 'the' which are excluded) I have put them into one of 5 categories based on my judgment. Here are the categories below and how I would expect them to be weighted:

- Tier 1 - words highly likely to determine a relationship - expect to be highly weighted.
- Tier 2 - words which could be relevant or could be irrelevant -
  expect to be less weighted.
- Tier 3 - words which are not likely to be relevant - expect to have
  very low weighting.
- Tier 4 - all words less commonly used than top 500 (not allocated to tier above) - not sure 
  how high this would be weighted. If this is weighted higher by a machine
  learning model than tier 3 this would indicate to me that I need to
  allocate more words to the first 3 tiers.
- Tier X - These are numbers which actually do indicate a relationship. 
  If these are not shared it is highly unlikely that two documents
  would be related so would expect it to have a very high weighting.

I figured that if I put this data and respective answers through a tensorflow model that has no hidden layers as in the picture below, the weightings should largely agree to the expectations above, and provide some numbers which could be useful in scoring documents against each other.

[image: screenshot; tensorflow model]

Here is a simplified version of my code to create and train the model:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.utils import plot_model
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import *

def main(data):

    model = keras.models.Sequential([
        keras.layers.Dense(1, input_shape=(5,), activation='relu')
    ])

    model.compile(optimizer='adam',
                  loss='mean_squared_error',
                  metrics=['accuracy'])

    train_profiles, train_answers = data 

    model.fit(train_profiles, train_answers, epochs=1)
    print(f"Current weights are: \n{model.get_weights()}")

    return model

if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = "I load a pickled data file from my computer - data is in correct format and throws no errors"
    main(data)
```

The problem is, the weights that are actually produced make no sense, and seem more random than anything, changing whenever the model is run. The accuracy is often quite high, ranging between 82% and 92% with loss of between 0.093 and 0.1350. I have corrected for class imbalance caused by significantly more occurrences of documents which are not related to each other by duplicating every matching document by 5000 so that the data fed to the model is approx 50/50 matching/not. I know this isn't the most efficient way to correct for class imbalance but training time isn't a big problem for me.

Note: input score is calculated as: 
   (number of times a word in this tier is shared by both documents) / 
   (total words in both documents)

Any methods to arrive at reasonable weightings for each tier would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Keep in mind that *duplicating every matching document by 5000* can lead to overfitting easiliy. You might try using *SMOTE* instead of simple duplications or maybe a mix between *SMOTE* and *undersampling*.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the direction of SMOTE. That will be very useful to me down the line. The seemingly random weights don't seem like overfitting though. I think given the presumably largely linear relationship between the number of matching words and whether two documents are related should be reflected in the weights of the model regardless of whether it is overfitted to my data.

Comment: Have you tried using a hidden layer?

Comment: Using a hidden layer results in more weights, but they are still not as expected. Remember, since there is expected to be a correlation between matching words and whether documents are related, the benefits of a hidden layer are not there. To contrast my use case with the classic mnist numbers example, having a high number of black pixels in an image does not indicate a high likelihood of an image being a higher number, so you need the hidden layers to recognize patterns. In my case, if all words are shared (compare to all pixels being black), this does indicate relationship.

Comment: `Using a hidden layer results in more weights, but they are still not as expected.` How do you expect the weights to be? Is your problem that the up to 92% accuracy is too bad for what you are trying to do? Or do you want to understand where the weights come from?